# Export data types from Salesforce

Tags: data-loader, fields

I am trying to create an excel sheet of all fields for all of my Salesforce custom objects. I need to include each field's API Name, field label, and data type.

However, when I do a bulk export using the Salesforce data loader, all that it exports is the API name of the field. The rest I currently have to look up in Salesforce and enter manually, which takes u a lot of time.

Are there any alternatives to Data Loader that would allow me to a bulk export of my field information, including each field's API Name, field label, and data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to track down an app for this from a related question (that did not appear when I first decided to post this).

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000018leZEAQ

Did the job very easily and well. I'm now looking to find a similar one for exporting workflow rules to excel.

Answer (score 1):

There's a free [Salesforce Lab](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003Ih3aEAC) that allows you to convert your objects and fields into data you can export in a report to Excel or any other spreadsheet program. There are a number of minor typos in labels and so on, but the code itself works flawlessly to export data. I am not the author of this package, but I have found it useful in the past. There are other alternatives as well, some paid, some free, if you need more power than that lab offers.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Field Trip](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4) for this use case.